# What is more sophisticated way to assign to tensor in tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was just wondering that if there is a better way of updating tensor in tf2. Let's say that I have `tensor_a = tf.ones(4,5,5)` (batch_size, H, W) and I would like to replace all the values of second sample by zeros(`index=1`). This is how I manage to do it without using Eager execution mode:

```
tensor_a = tf.ones([4,5,5])
tensor_b = tf.zeros([1,5,5])
index=1
tensor_a = tf.concat([tensor_a[:index], tensor_b, tensor_a[index+1:]], axis=0)
```

I know that there exists tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update() function but I'm not familiar with meshgrids and in my opinion they look a little bit ugly for simple slice assignment operation. Also in some cases it would be handy to update slices with many indexes (like samples 0,1 and 2 to zeros) at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow operations are a bit messy sometimes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.ones([4, 5, 5])

tensor = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(
    tensor, [[1]], tf.zeros_like(tf.gather(tensor, [1])) 
)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],
       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],
       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Aaah it was that simply with tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(). I was not familiar with indices parameter and I gave up before to trying with concat. Thanks!